# Quaternion integration

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, rotations, quaternions

If the angular velocity is changing continuously, the following holds true

$ q(t)=q(0)\exp\left({\int_{0}^{t}\frac{q_\omega(\tau)}{2}\ d\tau}\right) \tag 1$

**Specifications and Data**

1. $q(t),q(0)$ represents quaternions
2. $q_\omega(\tau)$ represents the quaternion representation of angular velocity at $\tau$. It implies  if $\omega(\tau) \in R^3 $ is the angular velocity,then  $q_\omega(\tau)=(0,\omega(\tau))$ at $\tau$
3. Exponent of a quaternion $J=( p,v)$  can be defined as 
   \begin{eqnarray}
    e^{J}=e^{p}\left(cos|v| ,\frac{v}{|v|}sin|v|  \right) 
   \end{eqnarray}$v$ is a vector. If you are given a vector, make it as a quaternion with $p=0$

**Question**

How do we prove equation $ q(t)=q(0)\exp\left({\int_{0}^{t}\frac{q_\omega(\tau)}{2}\ d\tau}\right)  $ precisely?

Comment: Looks like the solution to a separable differential equation. Something like $dq/dt = .5 q q_\omega$, ignoring what the proper multiplication is.

Comment: It seems you need to add detail to this question as to your precise definitions of differentiation etc. on the quaternions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/~mpersson/docs/quat_calc_notes.pdf gives what I think is essentially the same result,
$$ q(t) = q(t_0) \exp\left(\frac 12 \int_{t_0}^t \mathbf{\omega}(\tau) d\tau\right), $$
but this uses the following definition of the derivative of a quaternion
as a function of $t$:
$$
 \frac d{dt} \mathbf q(t) = 
 \lim_{\Delta t\rightarrow 0}
   \frac 1{\Delta t} 2\log(\mathbf q(t)^{-1}\mathbf q(t + \Delta t))
$$

Differential calculus over quaternions is also discussed in
http://web.mit.edu/2.998/www/QuaternionReport1.pdf 
and http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0310362.pdf, but those treatments seemed less helpful.